# Stopping stubborn container?

Tags: docker

I have a container open attached to a terminal, but `ctrl+C` and `crtl+D` are not working to stop it. Ergo, I opened another terminal and tried

```
docker stop CONTAINER_ID
```

where `CONTAINER_ID` is the ID of the container that is hung. This did not work, and hung that terminal. So I did a little internet research which led me to try

```
docker kill CONTAINER_ID
```

in another terminal. This also hung. So I searched a little more and found

```
docker rm -fv CONTAINER_ID
```

This, unfortunately, just hung in a fourth terminal. Is there a way to shut it down through docker that I'm missing, or do I need to start `kill -9`ing the processes with "docker" in their description?

I'm running Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22 on OSX.

Comment: What version of docker are you running, and on what platform?

Comment: @BMitch Question updated....but isn't the whole point of Docker that it's platform independent?

Comment: Try restarting the service from the whale menu, I've seen it get hung up, especially when changing ip addresses. How you administer the daemon varies on install type even if you can run the same containers on different installs.

Comment: @BMitch Nice! All the terminals gave me a `Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine` and back to the prompt. If you want to throw that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When docker hangs like that, I usually just restart the daemon and the clients will disconnect. On MacOS, that involves going to the whale drop down and running the restart from there. I often need to do this if my IP address changes.

Also, not relevant to you but may help others in the future, on earlier versions of docker (before 17.03) there is a deadlock issue especially with logs that would cause commands to hang. The solution is the same, restarting docker, but in this case I'd also recommend upgrading.

Comment: On linux possibly: `systemctl stop docker`, then `systemctl start docker`.