# Docker compose no response

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After **docker-compose down** and **docker-compose up** several times, sometime **docker-compose up** will cause no response. Normally, docker will tell you what container is created. But, nothing is shown. I try to quit Docker App and restart it. Cannot fix it. After restart OS, then docker-compose works fine.

Anyone know this issue?

**Update:**

Docker version: 1.12.0, build 8eab29e

Docker Composer Version: 1.8.0, build f3628c7

Platform: MacOS 10.11.4

Comment: What version of docker are you running and on what type of host?

Comment: Thanks @BMitch. i edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping stubborn container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794503/stopping-stubborn-container)

Comment: I'd suggest you begin by updating Docker. You should have Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e and docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245. After that, it'd be helpful to see your docker-compose.yml file so we can better diagnose. What output are you getting when running docker-compose up?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to run `docker-compose ps` to see what is currently running. If I were you I would like to kill the `ps` by running `docker-compose kill` and `docker-compose rm`. Atm the docker compose will be clean and you could run `docker-compose up` again

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the core issue. For my environment, i use Charles as proxy server. I enable the Mac OS proxy in Charles. Once, i disable it. Docker will work fine.

Answer (score -2):

Follow documentation on link:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

I used on Ubuntu 16.04 command:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.14.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

After that check if it works. Output should looks like:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.10.1, build b252738
```